# Content of the .First function does not appear to be processed when running in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile

In my `.Rprofile` I've defined the following `.First` function that has two purposes:

- Show available library paths
- Change the settings of [`colorout`](https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout) package if running RStudio with a bright theme

  ```
  .First <- function() {
      if (interactive()) {
         cat(
           "\nProcessed RProfile at:",
           date(),
           "\n",
           "Available libraries",
           "\n",
           paste(.libPaths(), collapse = "\n "),
           "\n"
           )

      # Check if running bright theme and adjust colour settings
      if (assertive::is_rstudio()) {
          theme_info <- rstudioapi::getThemeInfo()
          if (!theme_info$dark) {
              colorout::setOutputColors(
                  normal = 2,
                  negnum = 3,
                  zero = 3,
                  number = 3,
                  date = 3,
                  string = 6,
                  const = 5,
                  false = 5,
                  true = 2,
                  infinite = 5,
                  index = 2,
                  stderror = 4,
                  warn = c(1, 0, 1),
                  error = c(1, 7),
                  verbose = TRUE,
                  zero.limit = NA
              )
         }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

## Problem

When running in the terminal the function returns the desired results:
[image]

However, the content that would be generated by the `.First` function does not show:

[image]

also the colour settings do not seem to apply. 
When I source and call the function as `.First()` then it works with no problems.

I want to understand what is different about RStudio start-up that it does not produce equivalent results to R session running in the terminal and accessing same `.Rprofile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one thing, the entire body of the function is wrapped in `if(interactive()){}`.  The `interactive` function will return `TRUE` and therefore the code will run when you run your function from the command line.  But when `.First` is run automatically at startup, the `interactive` function returns `FALSE` and the entire body of the function is skipped.

It looks like when a session starts to be interactive may differ in the RStudio startup compared to Rterm.  You can test this by putting code like this at the beginning of `.First`:

```
if(interactive()) {
  cat('Interactive is TRUE\n')
} else {
  cat('Interactive is FALSE\n')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing the answer. I’m wondering, should the function remain unprocessed when running in terminal? This does not seem to be the case as starting R from command line produces results equivalent to sourcing and running .First “by hand”.

Comment: Your edit answers my comment, very interesting. That would explain why similar logic I’ve in .Last does not fail.